# GCP storage bucket wrong cname resolution

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-search-console

I'have created a **public readable**(all user) bucket with my verified subdomain name `static.<mydomain>.com`

I have verified my subdomain correctly. and also created a cname record in Cloudflare DNS manager for the "static" subdomain. which points to the `c.storage.googleapis.com`

`static.mydomain.com` >> `c.storage.googleapis.com`

when I access an asset inside that bucket through `static.<mydomain.com>/<asset_name>`
It redirects to `https://storage.googleapis.com/<previously_created_deleted_bucket_name>/<asset_name>` instead of `https://storage.googleapis.com/static.<mydomain>.com>/<asset_name>`

It doesn't select the correct bucket even though it redirects to storage.googleapis.com.

that page contains

```
<Error>
  <Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
  <Message>The specified bucket does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

**Why it is redirecting to a different bucket name (which is already deleted) other than the cname**?

most of the time Cloudflare DNS changes worked instantly. so that it is hard to believe that it is a DNS issue.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: In my case that was due to the delay of DNS propagation. It got fixed automatically after a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wait for about an hour and see. Even-though Cloudflare is fast to update the changes to your dns records, it takes some time for Google to pickup the changes and map the domain to the bucket.